# how do I install scripts like pg_lsclusters on a Amazon AWS Linux AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, postgresql, yum

I am used to debian/ubuntu distros and now trying to experiment with the official Amazon AWS Linux AMI.

I have installed postgresql-server, postgresql-devel, postgresql-contrib yum packages.

The problem is that I am missing commands like **pg_lsclusters**, **pg_ctlcluster**, etc.

What other package should I install to get these commands. Or are they available only on Debian based distros?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This commands (pg_*) comes from package [postgresql-common](http://packages.debian.org/en/lenny/postgresql-common), which is Debian specific. I think it's question to PostgreSQL's binary distribution maintainers (Amazon). I know it's not solution, but (probably) you can still use low level commands such as pg_ctl (pg_ctlcluster), initdb (pg_createcluster) etc. but of course it's not as handy as pg_*.